# NSString to Date Conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

2016-08-12 15:54:56+05:30 change String value to NSDate formate in same formate and values

```
Date = [DicArry valueForKey:@"start"]

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Date ];
```

I try above and get the result nil in date

Comment: There seem to be no issue with your code, I think you are not getting proper string from that dictionary, try to print its value.

Comment: What about setting the locale of the date formatter to `en_US`?

Comment: Is your system set to use am/pm rather than a 24 hour clock by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSString *Date = @"2016-08-12 15:54:56+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Date ];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

and you'll get right value.

So, check, did you get correct string from array:

```
Date = [DicArry valueForKey:@"start"];
NSLog(@"%@", Date);
```

P.S. Don't set variables name with first capital letter.

Comment: i am going to say the same about the variable name.